# QtMqtt not found in PySide6 instalation

Tags: python, pyside6, qt6

I am trying to use the QtMqtt client as part of a PySide6 project.  QT/Pyside docs say its supported: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-6.4/PySide6/QtMqtt/index.html.  When trying to import I get a Module Not Found.

I have tried pip installing which I expected that supported modules according to the docs with the install.

I have tried pip installing from the qt servers as described in their docs, https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-6.4/quickstart.html.  It is not included in this install either.

Has anybody encountered or solved this?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but I had success using [paho-mqtt](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) in a Qt/QML application. Just run the `paho.mqtt.client.Client` instance with `client.loop()` in a separate thread and in the `on_message` callback dispatch messages by emitting custom Qt signals, which then can be handled by your QtWidgets code or in your QML.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](https://qtinfo.dev/qtforpython/#/19), it might only be available for the commercial edition (it would fall under the M2M protocols category).